# How to save java objects with circular references with Morphia? Is it even supported?

Tags: mongodb, morphia

I was trying to store these two classes in my MongoDB database:

**Player class**

```
@Entity(value = "players")
public class SMPPlayer {

    @Id
    protected final String uuidString;
    protected OfflinePlayer offlinePlayer;
    @Reference
    protected City city;

    public SMPPlayer(OfflinePlayer offlinePlayer) {
        this.offlinePlayer = offlinePlayer;
        this.uuidString = offlinePlayer.getUniqueId().toString();
        
    }

    public SMPPlayer(OfflinePlayer offlinePlayer, String uuidString, City city) {
        this.offlinePlayer = offlinePlayer;
        this.uuidString = uuidString;
        this.city = city;
    }

    public SMPPlayer(OnlineSMPPlayer onlineSMPPlayer) {
        this(onlineSMPPlayer.offlinePlayer, onlineSMPPlayer.uuidString,
                onlineSMPPlayer.city,
                onlineSMPPlayer.country
        );
    }

    public SMPPlayer() {
        this.offlinePlayer = null;
        this.uuidString = null;
    }

    public SMPPlayer(UUID uuid) {
        this.offlinePlayer = Bukkit.getOfflinePlayer(uuid);
        this.uuidString = uuid.toString();
    }

    public OfflinePlayer getOfflinePlayer() {
        return offlinePlayer;
    }

    public UUID getUniqueId() {
        return UUID.fromString(uuidString);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof SMPPlayer)) return false;
        SMPPlayer that = (SMPPlayer) o;
        return Objects.equals(uuidString, that.uuidString);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getOfflinePlayer(), uuidString);
    }

    public City getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    /**
     * Adds player to the given city if not null and if player isnt already in a city.
     *
     * @param city
     */

    public void setCity(City city) {
        City cityPlayerIsActuallyIn = getCity();
        if (city != null) {
            if (cityPlayerIsActuallyIn == null) {
                city.addPlayer(this);
            }
        } else {
            if (cityPlayerIsActuallyIn != null) {
                cityPlayerIsActuallyIn.kickPlayer(this);
            }
        }
    }

    public String getName() {
        return offlinePlayer.getName();
    }

    public boolean isOnline() {
        return false;
    }

    @PostLoad
    public void postLoad() {
        this.offlinePlayer = Bukkit.getOfflinePlayer(UUID.fromString(uuidString));
    }

}
```

**City class:**

```
@Entity(value = "cities")
public class City extends PointOfInterest implements
        FoundingRequestable,
        CanBeInvitedTo,
        Comparable<City>
{

    @Id
    private ObjectId id;

    private Set<SMPPlayer> players;
    private Set<SMPPlayer> mayors;

    private EmbeddedBanner banner;


    public City() {
        super(null, null);
    }

    public City(String name, Location location, EmbeddedBanner banner) {
        super(name, new EmbeddedSimpleLocation(location));
        this.players = new HashSet<>();
        this.mayors = new HashSet<>();
        this.banner = banner;
    }
}
```

Notice how SMPPlayer references a City object, and how City references a Set of SMPPlayer objects.
When I invoke datastore.getMapper().map(SMPPlayer.class, City.class); it throws an error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl cannot be cast to class java.lang.Class (sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl and java.lang.Class are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

    at dev.morphia.mapping.codec.pojo.TypeData.getNestedTypeData(TypeData.java:96)
    at dev.morphia.mapping.codec.pojo.TypeData.newInstance(TypeData.java:80)
    at dev.morphia.mapping.codec.pojo.TypeData.newInstance(TypeData.java:64)
    at dev.morphia.mapping.codec.pojo.EntityModelBuilder.processFields(EntityModelBuilder.java:351)
    at dev.morphia.mapping.codec.pojo.EntityModelBuilder.<init>(EntityModelBuilder.java:82)
    at dev.morphia.mapping.Mapper.createEntityModel(Mapper.java:502)
    at dev.morphia.mapping.Mapper.getEntityModel(Mapper.java:129)
    at dev.morphia.mapping.validation.fieldrules.ReferenceToUnidentifiable.check(ReferenceToUnidentifiable.java:33)
    at dev.morphia.mapping.validation.fieldrules.FieldConstraint.check(FieldConstraint.java:18)
    at dev.morphia.mapping.validation.MappingValidator.validate(MappingValidator.java:62)
    at dev.morphia.mapping.Mapper.register(Mapper.java:651)
    at dev.morphia.mapping.Mapper.getEntityModel(Mapper.java:129)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractList$RandomAccessSpliterator.forEachRemaining(AbstractList.java:720)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
    at dev.morphia.mapping.Mapper.map(Mapper.java:305)
    at dev.morphia.mapping.Mapper.map(Mapper.java:142)
    at net.earomc.smp.core.test.MorphiaBugTest.testMapMethod(MorphiaBugTest.java:14)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

When I tried to remove the circular references it didn't throw the error.
Doesn't Morphia support circular references? I haven't found anything on this.

How can I achieve storing and retrieving both of these objects without destroying the object relations?

Or do I need to change the entire system so that there isn't a circular reference in the first place? For example: Only saving player ids in the city object.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add `@Reference` in `City` when referring back to `SMPPlayer`.  Otherwise it's trying to save them as embedded docs which get weird.

UPDATE:  This bug has been fixed in 2.1.5 and was unrelated to circular refs.  It was actually a bug in the generics parsing in Morphia.

Comment: I tried that. But it still gives me the error. What does the error mean?

Comment: Hrm.  Curious.  What version of Morphia are you on?  Could you put together a [reproducer](https://github.com/MorphiaOrg/reproducer) and I can try to dig in to it?

Comment: I was on 2.1.3. I just updated to 2.1.4 and ran the test again and now it's an entirely different error: https://pastebin.com/wiQiyC4a
This time it happens when creating a new Datastore. 
I tried to recreate the issue with your reproducer, however the tests passed without any errors ...

Comment: Ok, little update: I was able to get the *second* error I talked about on the reproducer. It appears only when having installed the mongodb java driver as maven dependency.

Comment: PS: heres the link to my reproducer https://github.com/earomc/reproducer
I was using mongodb java driver version 3.12.4